# I have a list in which items are getting added at any index dynamically , so i want to get the latest element added in list?

Tags: python

`a = [5,2,7]`

If 2 is the latest element added in a then return 2 .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
>>> list_ = [0, 1, 2]
>>> list_[-1]
2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of knowing how a list was modified. Python does not keep track of this information. This means you would have to keep a copy of the list before updating it and run something like

```
a = [5,2,7]
old_a = a.copy()
a[1] = 0
[old_a[i] for i,v in enumerate(a) if old_a[i]!=v]
```

However, if you are able to keep track of this, you are certainly able to keep track of the added value, and to run the tests before adding it to the new list. In summary, the design of what you are doing should probably be reconsidered.